# Can you customise the build version dropdown for a VSTS Release Defintion

Tags: azure-devops, release

When you are using the online Visual Studio Team Services for the build/release process, I find the window/wizard for creating a new release to be a bit limiting. At the moment for me, when I want to pick which version of an artifact(s) I want to  release it only lists the build version number, which is a pain when you have multiple artifacts built from different branches and don't necessarily always want the latest build of each.

[image]

Is it possible to customise this build version dropdown to include something else (like the branch it was built from)? I've tried changing the output artifact name in the build definition, thinking maybe that would be picked up in the release wizard, but it isn't.

Comment: Did you change the build name successful as you want by the way Daniel said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the build name output format on the Options tab of the build definition. The variable you're looking for here is `$(SourceBranchName)`.

As an example:

`$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)-$(SourceBranchName)`

Comment: Yeah that solves the problem. I was trying to change the artifact name on the final publish task to use the branch name variable, didn't think to change the build number format in the options tab. Thanks